# Invoking a method via reflection causes System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system.reflection

I am loading an assembly dynamically and invoking a static method from it. The problem arises when the method uses a reference which is not trivial (e.g. mscorlib or System.Core) - I get `System.MissingMethodException`. I have tried going through the references assemblies of the loaded assembly and manually loading them all, thus forcing them to be loaded onto the AppDomain. I have checked `CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies`, the assemblies are loaded.

The reference is a 3rd party library and I know the correct version is loaded (from `CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies`).

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Make sure you load assemblies before JITting the method,

Comment: @SLaks the code is as simple as calling `Assembly.LoadFrom`, finding type, finding static method, calling invoke with no arguments. The assembly loading code is done before the invoke by iterating over the referenced assemblies (and as I've said, the AppDomain object recognizes the loading).

Comment: This is probably an issue with the LoadFrom context.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx

Comment: @SLaks This message has caught my attention: "If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and later an assembly in the load context attempts to load same the assembly by display name, the load attempt fails.", but the problem persists when I do not have the assembly-loading loop.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is from nine years ago. I was still in high school back then :)

Comment: @RamonSnir: Ah - it came up on the front page due to the new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I musn't be the first one figured this out after 8 years...

When using `AssemblyResolve` or `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` to resolve assemblies from custom location, you have to make sure the assembly **instance** loaded through, say `Assembly.Load`, is unique, as same names might be passed into `AssemblyResolve`... The AppDomain is confusing itself, as it is not caching the loaded assemblies!!

```
    private static Dictionary<string, Assembly> _resolved = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

    private static Assembly ResolveDependencies(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_resolved.ContainsKey(args.Name))
        {
            return _resolved[args.Name];
        }

        var asm = Assembly.Load(GetEmbeddedAssembly(args.Name));
        _resolved[args.Name] = asm;
        return asm;
    }
```

Come on microsoft, you really can document this better!

Comment: Hi @zhywu thanks for your answer. Nowadays I'm dealing with this issue when I use Assembly.Load() to load an array of bytes with the assembly. I appreciate if you can give more detail about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using for invoking that static method?

I would use:

```
typeof(YourType).GetMethod("YourMethodName", 
     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, your_params);
```

If by any chance the method is actually implemented in the base class you will need:

```
typeof(YourType).GetMethod("YourMethodName", 
     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
  .Invoke(null, your_params);
```

If the method is not public, you will have to add `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

As you want it from the external assembly, use `Assembly.GetType()` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: Method is public, is found and can be invoked. The problem is that while it executed (not necessarily immediately) it tried to call a method from one of its references (which as I've said, is loaded onto the AppDomain) and fails with MissingMethodException.